# Format coded fields

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

in cakePHP I have some fields which ar option fields and does not come from database:

*View/Controller/index.ctp*

```
<?php echo $model['Model']['option']; ?>
```

*View/Controller/add.ctp*

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Model'); ?>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('option', array(
                'label' => __('Option'),
                'options' => array(
                    0 => __('Foo'),
                    1 => __('Bar'),
                    2 => __('Static')
                )
            )
        );
    ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

I want `index.ctp` (and `show.ctp`) showing `Foo/Bar/Static`, not `0/1/n`, which is what are showing so far..

Comment: why would you even use a select box for booleans? two states is per definition a boolean and therefore what a checkbox usually stands for.

Comment: @mark it is a sample, I can change it to whatever, which will be a static option, not populated from database.

Answer (score 0):

It seems ok. But you should use $this->request->data to display datas of the form and the debug() function to debug.

So, what you see with:

```
debug($this->request->data[Model]['option'])
```

Comment: Apart from that you have edited the question ... the first was different.

But the answer does not change. You can read form datas with 
`$this->request->data.`
I don't know what is `$model['Model']['option']` ???

Comment: I have edited only `True/False` to `Foo/Bar/Static`. `index.ctp` have a list of data come from a model `$models`, which I do a foreach. Yes, $this->request->data gives-me the data, but, when I post some form. Now, imagine I am getting all data from database. `$model['Model']['option']` will return `0`, if I select `Foo` option. What I want is it show `Foo`, like if this option are comming from database.